# How to Get Accuracy Measures for Nine(9) Sub-series in a loop

Tags: r, windows, loops, forecasting, arima

I want to get the `accuracy measures` for 9 different subseries`as described in my`R loop` below with the following steps:

1. Simulate a 10 sample of `AR(1)` series.
2. Split the series into subseries of size `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` without overlapping.
3. Resample the subseries 1000 times each block size with replacement.
4. Form a new series by joining all the resampled subseries for each block size.
5. Check the `accuracy` (**ME, RMSE, MAE, MPE, MAPE**) of the newly formed NINE(9) SUB-series for each block size.

as follows:

```
################################################################################
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())

## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
N10_ar0.8_seed289805 <- arima.sim(n=10, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
auto.arima(N10_ar0.8_seed289805, ic="aicc")

########################################################
## create a vector of block sizes
t <- length(N10_ar0.8_seed289805)    # the length of the time series
lb <- seq(t-1) #seq(t-2)+1   # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
########################################################
## This section create matrix to store block means
BOOTSTRAP <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
colnames(BOOTSTRAP) <- lb
########################################################
## This section use foreach function to do detail in the brace
#set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
BOOTSTRAP <- foreach(b = 1:length(lb), .combine = 'cbind', .packages = c("forecast", "Metrics")) %dopar%{
  l <- lb[b]# block size at each instance 
  m <- ceiling(t / l)                                 # number of blocks
  blk <- split(N10_ar0.8_seed289805, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t))  # divides the series into blocks
  ######################################################
  set.seed(5)
  res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 1000)        # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
  mod <- auto.arima(res.unlist)
  fit <- fitted(mod)
  ACCURACY <- forecast::accuracy(fit, res.unlist)      # RETURNS ACCURACY
  BOOTSTRAP[b] <- ACCURACY
}
BOOTSTRAPS <- matrix(BOOTSTRAP, nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
colnames(BOOTSTRAPS) <- lb
BOOTSTRAPS
```

I got:

```
#                 1        2        3         4        5            6        7        8        9
# [1,] -0.0001474358 1.576266 1.298314 -1.210742 204.8705 0.0002838375 1.413514 1.129676 8.073587
```

**I want to get something like this:**

```
Statistic   1      2        3       4      5        6      7      8       9
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSE       0.886   1.021    0.8866  0.886  1.021    0.886  0.886  1.021    0.886
MAE       0.762   0.835    0.762   0.762  0.835    0.762  0.762  0.835    0.762
MAPE      3.859   2.263    3.859   3.859  2.263    3.859  3.859  2.263    3.859
ME       -0.005   0.381   -0.005   -0.005 0.381    -0.005 -0.005 0.381    -0.005
MPE      -0.086   1.004   -0.086   -0.086 1.004    -0.086 -0.086 1.004   -0.086
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACCURACY` is a 1 row matrix:

```
ACCURACY
                   ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE
Test set 0.0002838375 1.413514 1.129676 8.073587 205.3605

dim(ACCURACY)
[1] 1 5
```

You could use `rbind` instead of `cbind` and transpose the final result.
Note that you don't need to define `BOOTSTRAP` as it's directly returned by `foreach` :

```
################################################################################
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())

## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
N10_ar0.8_seed289805 <- arima.sim(n=10, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
auto.arima(N10_ar0.8_seed289805, ic="aicc")

########################################################
## create a vector of block sizes
t <- length(N10_ar0.8_seed289805)    # the length of the time series
lb <- seq(t-1) #seq(t-2)+1   # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
########################################################

########################################################
## This section use foreach function to do detail in the brace
#set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
BOOTSTRAP <- foreach(b = 1:length(lb), .combine = 'rbind', .packages = c("forecast", "Metrics")) %dopar%{
  l <- lb[b]# block size at each instance 
  m <- ceiling(t / l)                                 # number of blocks
  blk <- split(N10_ar0.8_seed289805, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t))  # divides the series into blocks
  ######################################################
  set.seed(5)
  res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 1000)        # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
  mod <- auto.arima(res.unlist)
  fit <- fitted(mod)
  ACCURACY <- forecast::accuracy(fit, res.unlist)      # RETURNS ACCURACY
  ACCURACY
}
BOOTSTRAPS <- t(BOOTSTRAP)
colnames(BOOTSTRAPS) <- lb
BOOTSTRAPS


                 1            2             3             4            5             6             7             8            9
ME   -1.474358e-04 2.838375e-04 -1.109465e-04 -3.546411e-04 4.991512e-05 -5.613602e-04 -2.061036e-04 -2.793918e-04  -0.00016262
RMSE  1.576266e+00 1.413514e+00  1.407372e+00  1.226815e+00 1.142930e+00  1.089578e+00  1.025063e+00  9.066126e-01   0.86546536
MAE   1.298314e+00 1.129676e+00  1.111374e+00  8.359341e-01 7.644257e-01  8.700083e-01  8.375352e-01  7.335306e-01   0.66246307
MPE  -1.210742e+00 8.073587e+00 -6.381357e+00  2.462817e+01 8.554913e+01  1.980497e+01  2.027281e+01 -2.615038e+01 -32.72766437
MAPE  2.048705e+02 2.053605e+02  1.922015e+02  1.500389e+02 1.533140e+02  1.768961e+02  1.665399e+02  1.436919e+02 140.63999983
```